# How to add an update statement value to a variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to save data in a variable and use it later in a procedure.

```
UPDATE  acc_Account
                SET     acc_Account.CompanyID = ( SELECT TOP 1
                                                          utl_Company.CompanyID
                                                  FROM    utl_Company
                                                  ORDER BY CompanyID DESC
                                                )
                WHERE   acc_Account.AccountNumber = @AccountNumber
```

how can I save the CompanyID in a variable to use it in an insert statement later on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have this in the beginning of your code:

```
declare @var varchar(20) -- change the data type according to your needs
set @var = (SELECT TOP 1 utl_Company.CompanyID FROM utl_Company ORDER BY CompanyID DESC)
```

Comment: This is the right way to do this. One suggestion I would make to the OP though is to use select MIN(CompanyID) instead of top 1 and order. It is easier to understand and is slight performance gain if the table is large.

Comment: @Bishoy Ezzat - before would be fine.

Comment: @BishoyEzzat using it before would allow you to then do `UPDATE  acc_Account
                SET     acc_Account.CompanyID = @var WHERE   acc_Account.AccountNumber = @AccountNumber`, which obviously saves you running the query a second time within the update.

Comment: @ADyson so I can use after '@var' the update statement .. it saves the update statement ?!

Comment: @Bishoy Ezzat: What ADyson means is that you can:
1. Set the variable as shown above.
2. Then use it in the update statement as shown by ADyson.

As the variable has already been set, the update statement will run faster (and the procedure itself, assuming you will be using the variable later on again).

Answer (score 2):

Create a [select local variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx) before the update statement, then set it, then use it.

```
DECLARE @companyID INT;
SELECT @companyID = "YOUR QUERY";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the efficient way would be using `OUTPUT` clause

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (CompanyID BIGINT  )
UPDATE acc_Account
SET acc_Account.CompanyID = (
        SELECT max(CompanyID) FROM utl_Company
        )
output inserted.CompanyID into @TAB
WHERE acc_Account.AccountNumber = @AccountNumber

SELECT * FROM @TAB
```